# MATLAB last plot in subplot overlays other plots

Tags: matlab, subplot

Firstly, apologies in advance, as I'm new to MATLAB (and coding).

I'm trying to put multiple plots in a subplot (4,9,n) however the last plot overlays the rest of the plots and is the only one containing data.

I'd like each plot to look like something like this:
[Line plot with two x axes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXaNP.png)

Here's a snippet of the code I'm using (because I'm new, I haven't used a loop, so I've got code for each separate figure!):

```
%% TMR2    
%set up data
TMR2 = HEOBI1{HEOBI1.STNNBR==2,:}
x1 = TMR2(:,[4])
x2 = TMR2(:,[5])
x3 = TMR2(:,[7])/25
y = TMR2(:,[3])
%set up figure in subplot
subplot(4,9,1)
%set up secondary (H2O2) axis
b=axes('Position',[.1 .1 .8 1e-12]);
set(b,'Units','normalized');
set(b,'Color','none');
b.XColor=[0 153/255 0];
%primary plot (DFE and FEII)
a=axes('Position',[.1 .2 .8 .7]);
set(a,'Units','normalized');
plot(x1,y,'-o','Color',[221/255 15/255 4/255],...
'MarkerFaceColor',[221/255 15/255 4/255])
set(gca,'Ydir','reverse')
xlim([0 3])
hold on
plot(x2,y,'-o','Color',[0 153/255 153/255],...
'MarkerFaceColor',[0 153/255 153/255])
plot(x3,y,'-o','Color',[0 153/255 0],...
'MarkerFaceColor',[0 153/255 0])
hold off
title('2')
%Set secondary (H2O2) axis limit
set(b,'xlim',[0 25]*3);
```

Finishing with:

```
%% TMR40
%set up data
TMR40 = HEOBI1{HEOBI1.STNNBR==40,:}
x1 = TMR40(:,[4])
x2 = TMR40(:,[5])
x3 = TMR40(:,[7])/25
y = TMR40(:,[3])
%set up figure in subplot
subplot(4,9,36)
%set up secondary (H2O2) axis
b=axes('Position',[.1 .1 .8 1e-12]);
set(b,'Units','normalized');
set(b,'Color','none');
b.XColor=[0 153/255 0];
%primary plot (DFE and FEII)
a=axes('Position',[.1 .2 .8 .7]);
set(a,'Units','normalized');
plot(x1,y,'-o','Color',[221/255 15/255 4/255],...
'MarkerFaceColor',[221/255 15/255 4/255])
set(gca,'Ydir','reverse')
xlim([0 3])
hold on
plot(x2,y,'-o','Color',[0 153/255 153/255],...
'MarkerFaceColor',[0 153/255 153/255])
plot(x3,y,'-o','Color',[0 153/255 0],...
'MarkerFaceColor',[0 153/255 0])
hold off
title('40')
%Set secondary (H2O2) axis limit
set(b,'xlim',[0 25]*3);
```

And here's what my final output looks like:
[Incorrect Subplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRCSB.png)

@Suever I thought about your suggestion a bit more and took out all code for `axes` for each of the subplots. I then set up the `subplot` with handles and gave each subplot a handle. My code now starts like this:

```
%% Subplot setup
figure;
for k = 1:36
    h(k) = subplot(4,9,k);
end
```

and the code for each subplot now looks like this:

```
%% TMR40
%set up data
TMR40 = HEOBI1{HEOBI1.STNNBR==40,:}
x1 = TMR40(:,[4])
x2 = TMR40(:,[5])
x3 = TMR40(:,[7])/25
y = TMR40(:,[3])
%set up plot
subplot(h(36))
%primary plot (DFE and FEII)
plot(x1,y,'-o','Color',[221/255 15/255 4/255],...
'MarkerFaceColor',[221/255 15/255 4/255])
set(gca,'Ydir','reverse')
xlim([0 3])
hold on
plot(x2,y,'-o','Color',[0 153/255 153/255],...
'MarkerFaceColor',[0 153/255 153/255])
plot(x3,y,'-o','Color',[0 153/255 0],...
'MarkerFaceColor',[0 153/255 0])
hold off
title('40')
```

The subplots are now displaying correctly and I can edit individual subplots with their respective handles. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems like you're confused about what `subplot` does and your terminology is a bit off. You don't "setup a figure in a `subplot`". A figure is the entire window that holds all of your plots, and `subplot` is an `axes` that holds your various plot objects (lines, images, surfaces, etc.).

The main issue though is that `subplot` *creates an `axes`*. This means that you don't need to call `axes()` after calling `subplot` otherwise that call to `axes` will create a new `axes` that does not obey the layout of the `subplot` inputs.

So instead of

```
subplot(9,4,36)
a = axes('Position', [.1 .2 .8 .7]);
plot(x, y)
```

Just do

```
subplot(9,4,36)
plot(x,y)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Suever. However, upon deleting `a=axes('Position',[.1 .2 .8 .7]);` I get a 4x9 of empty plots with some data squished right down the bottom. See ![here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8C4a-b2ohkydF9LM2Jta1JGejg/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: @Tom Can you post the actual code used to generate that?